# Get .data() from an object from another frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using .data() to store an object-instance to a DOM element. This works within the frame I'm in but due to regulation within the application I'm working on all jQuery dialogs are filled using an iframe. For some reason I can't seem to access the .data() stored object from outside the frame. Any way how I can access it?

My code to store the object (which is an CodeMirror-instance).

`$('#MyTextArea').data('CodeMirrorEditor', editor);` (where `editor` is the instance)

When I want to access it I'm using:

```
var context = document.getElementById('DialogFrame').contentWindow.document);
console.log($('#MyTextArea', context);
console.log($('#MyTextArea', context).data('CodeMirrorEditor'));
```

The first log results in the textarea being logged. Which is correct, because the ID referred to is a `<textarea>`.
The second log results in `undefined`. For some reason the stored instance of `editor` is lost or not accessible from outside the frame.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Comment: I think that there is a security problem.. Browsers don't let you manipulate frames content with javascript

Comment: is the content of the frame on the same site? otherwise you cant regarding security issues.

Comment: I think jQuery's internal cache which `data()` uses is keyed by the page URL, so the containing page won't be able to access data stored in the iframe.

Comment: I don't want to manipulate it. I need the object again so I can call for the method `getValue()`. I'm using `xajax` to post the form but since the textarea is overlayed with CodeMirror I need to manually call for this method to get the current content, and not the content which has been assigned to it when the editor was created.

Comment: Rory, if what you're are saying is true than there won't be a solution to my problem I guess. But didn't they invent the optional context parameter for this?

Comment: It the iframe is of your own domain then you can use jQuery contents to access the element and all the attributes of the element

Comment: Zahid, I don't need the DOM element, I need the stored object within the DOM object (MyTextArea). By the way, my first log does what `contents()` can do as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with the context, but with the jQuery object itself.
Since the data() properties are set within the jQuery object that was defined in the original page, of course the new jQuery object can't access them.

To solve this, use the original jQuery object:

```
myOrigWindow.jQuery('some-selector').data(...);
```